# Enabling cross-origin resource sharing on Apache Flume

Tags: cors, flume, flume-ng

I am developing a web-page that basically connects to the Flume server through port 8080. Every time that the client sends a new petition, it throws 403 Forbidden error, because the HTTP source does not know how to handle OPTIONS requests.

There is no specific mention in the documentation of Apache Flume on how to enable CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to modify Flume's source code.

In the file [HTTPSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.flume/flume-ng-core/1.5.0-cdh5.4.3/org/apache/flume/source/http/HTTPSource.java) (private class *FlumeHTTPServlet*), add the following method:

```
@Override
public void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException
{
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a nginx proxy in front of flume to set the CORS headers instead of doing it with flume.

Here is my proxy definition:

```
server {
#proxy server for flume
listen   15140; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS' always;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Origin,Accept,token' always;
                add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
                add_header Content-Length 0;
                return 200;
    }

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS' always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Origin,Accept,token' always;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:5140/;
}
```

Hopefully this helps